# How to use setxkbmap from tty?

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard-layout

I'm confused about using `setxkbmap`. When I use it in my terminal emulator under X, it works:

```
setxkbmap -layout gr -option # switches layout to greek
```

However, if I switch to tty2, execute the command (with proper DISPLAY set) and switch back to X, layout does not change:

```
DISPLAY=:0 setxkbmap -layout gr -option
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Setting `DISPLAY` is not enough. Have you set `XAUTHORITY`, too? Is this the same user in tty and X? Can you start any X program from tty?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - Yes, I tried setting XAUTHORITY, too, confirmed that it was the same in tty and X. Yes, the same user, and all X programs start just fine. setxkbmap also exits without errors (without DISPLAY it complained about unable to open default display).

Comment: I suggest you run `setxkbmap` through `strace` in tty and an X terminal emulator and compare the outputs.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - did that, output is identical (modulo memory addresses)

Answer (score 0):

The X server must be active when you execute that command from a TTY.

```bsh
export DISPLAY=:0 # Your Display
sleep 1 && setxkbmap us # Change keyboard layout
```

So I recommend you to execute that command and then, immediately switch to your X display for the changes to be applied.

You can see this behaviour on the `xclip -o` command.
When executed on the TTY, it waits before the X server is active to print out the content of the primary clipboard.